# Vim find either pattern P or Q if occurring withing K lines of current line # N

Tags: vim

I am editing line number N in a text file open in `vim`. I would like to find all occurrences of either patter P or pattern Q if and only if they appear in line numbers in the inclusive range [N-K, N+K], with K being the value of a defined variable. Is such a thing possible at all? It would be the basic of a much needed script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:-5,+5g/P\|Q
```

shows all the lines containing `P` *or* `Q` between 5 lines above the current line and 5 lines below.

See `:help search()` if you want to do that into a script.

See `:help range` for more info on ranges.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted either P _or_ Q, would that still be possible?